# Windows XP right-click mouse option to send shortcut to desktop gone

Tags: windows-xp, desktop, shortcuts

Windows XP right-click mouse option to send shortcut to desktop suddenly gone

Answer (score 2):

It's possible the shortcut was deleted accidentally by you or someone else using your machine.

You can follow the steps at this [Microsoft Knowledge Base article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310270) to locate the "Send To" folder and add it back yourself.